# Calculation from 3 inputs

Tags: android, calculator, calculation

Im quite new to all of this and am trying to write a basic app for a work project using android studio. The purpose of the app is to work out a calculation which is "answer=1.25 x (Standby x Quiescent) + (1.75 x Alarm/2). The 3 user inputs are standby, quiescent and alarm. 
I have built the UI and done a lot of the java but i can not for the life of me work out how to do the actual calculation its self when someone hits the bt_calculate button

Could anyone please help or at least point me in the right direction with this?

```
package batterycalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BatteryCalculator extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText QuiescentCurrent;
private EditText AlarmCurrent;
private EditText Standby;

private TextView ah_result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_battery_calculator);

    QuiescentCurrent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.@+id/QuiescentCurrent);
    AlarmCurrent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.@+id/AlarmCurrent);
    Standby = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.@+id/Standby);

    Button bt_calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_calculate);

    bt_calculate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.@+id/bt_calculate);

    bt_calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            makeCalculations();
        }
    });
}

private void makeCalculations() {

///CALCULATION HERE

    result.setText( result+"Ah");
}

}
```

Edit: Have now got the calculation in but for the life of me i can not get it to work when pushing the button. As i say, im new to this and trying to teach myself java but im seeing so many conflicting ways to make it work but none seem to work for me! Here is my current code. Can anyone help?

```
package batterycalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class BatteryCalculator extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText quiescentcurrent;
    private EditText alarmcurrent;
    private EditText standbytime;
    private TextView ahresult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_battery_calculator);

        quiescentcurrent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quiescentcurrent);
        alarmcurrent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.alarmcurrent);
        standbytime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.standbytime);
        ahresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ahresult);

        Button btcalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btcalculate);
        btcalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 makeCalculations();
            }
            private void makeCalculations() {

                 double quiescent = 
Double.parseDouble(quiescentcurrent.getText().toString());
                double alarm = 
Double.parseDouble(alarmcurrent.getText().toString());
            double standby = 
Double.parseDouble(standbytime.getText().toString());

            double answer = 1.25 * (standby * quiescent) + (1.75 * alarm / 
2);
            ahresult.setText(String.valueOf(answer));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Double.parseDouble instead, but same overall  solution

Answer (score 0):

```
private void makeCalculations() {

   double quiescent = Double.parseDouble(QuiescentCurrent.getText().toString());
   double alarm = Double.parseDouble(AlarmCurrent.getText().toString());
   double standby= Double.parseDouble(Standby.getText().toString());

   double answer = 1.25 * (standby * quiescent) + (1.75 * alarm/2);
   result.setText(String.valueof(answer));
}
```

A few notes:

. You must initialize the `result` TextView;

. You should not start the variable names with an uppercase letter;

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate that. I have now got the code done and debugged but when testing, the button seems to not do anything. I have spent some time looking around for answers but i am getting a lot of conflicting resolutions none of which seem to work here. Ive added my new code in the original post, would anyone be able to give me some pointers? Im really keen to learn this but im struggling here!

Comment: @Harni why did you put the `makeCalculations` function inside the listener? It does not make sense

Comment: My mistake and i glad you pointed that out. It did work like that though. I worked out what the problem was and i feel incredibly stupid for not noticing it! Text size on the ahresult was set to 0sp! Thanks for your help!